# How to erase child from boost tree if it is double registered?

Tags: c++, boost, tree, double

Could you please help me with the following?

I populate this finalTree = treeA + treeB

However, the problem is that some elements of treeB have the same name with some of treeA. As a result I might have double registries for some children.

ie.

```
    <category>
        <fruit type="banana">
              <characteristic>
                 <point v="0"/>
              </characteristic>
        </fruit>
        <fruit type="orange">
              <characteristic>
                 <point v="1"/>
               </characteristic>
        </fruit>
        <fruit type="banana">
              <characteristic>
                  <point v="2"/>
              </characteristic>
        </fruit>
        <fruit type="fig">
              <characteristic>
                <point v="3"/>
              </characteristic>
        </fruit>
    </category>
```

What I want to achieve is to delete the first entry of banana and keep the last.
So far I do:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree  & node = informationTree.add("information.fruitTypes", "");
node.add("<xmlattr>.type", fruit);
node.add_child("characteristic", char);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to remove it, as I don't know whether the double entry will be banana or something else the next time. Should I copy populate tree? What do you suggest please?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just building the tree, you can just use `put_*` instead of `add_*` and it would overwrite an element if it already exists by that name.

If you have a tree and want to remove the duplicates at a certain subtree, you have to do it manually, e.g.:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df5acfb952d09daf)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;

template <typename KeyF>
ptree nodup(ptree const& pt, KeyF key_accessor) {
    ptree filtered;
    std::map<std::string, std::reference_wrapper<ptree> > seen;

    for (auto& entry : pt) {
        auto key      = key_accessor(entry);
        auto previous = seen.find(key);

        if (seen.end() == previous)
            seen.emplace(key, filtered.add_child(entry.first, entry.second));
        else
            previous->second.get() = entry.second; // overwrite
    }

    return filtered;
}

int main() {
    ptree pt;
    {
        std::istringstream iss( "<category><fruit type=\"banana\"><characteristic><point v=\"0\"/></characteristic></fruit><fruit type=\"orange\"><characteristic><point v=\"1\"/></characteristic></fruit><fruit type=\"banana\"><characteristic><point v=\"2\"/></characteristic></fruit><fruit type=\"fig\"><characteristic><point v=\"3\"/></characteristic></fruit></category>");
        read_xml(iss, pt);
    }
    write_xml(std::cout, pt, boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4, "utf-8"));

    auto& subtree = pt.get_child("category");
    subtree = nodup(subtree, [](ptree::value_type const& item) { return item.second.get("<xmlattr>.type", ""); });

    write_xml(std::cout, pt, boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4, "utf-8"));
}
```

If you are a bit more performance concerned, you can iterate backwards and avoid some overwrite actions:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4087fd0bce6f2998)</kbd>**

```
template <typename KeyF>
ptree nodup(ptree const& pt, KeyF key_accessor) {
    ptree filtered;
    std::map<std::string, std::reference_wrapper<ptree> > seen;

    for (auto entry = pt.rbegin(), last = pt.rend(); entry != last; ++entry) {
        auto key      = key_accessor(*entry);
        auto previous = seen.find(key);

        if (seen.end() == previous)
            seen.emplace(key, filtered.add_child(entry->first, entry->second));
    }

    return filtered;
}
```

However, keep in mind this potentially alters the order in which the fruits appear in the subtree.